# ReferenceError: Error #1069:Property not found on String and there is no default value

Tags: php, string, actionscript-3, flash, url

I am loading an external php file in flash using URLRequest. But unfortunately I get this error-

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069:Property email not found on String and there is no default value.
    at Main/variablesGot()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

Here is the relevant as3 code

```
phpLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, variablesGot);    
private function variablesGot(ev:Event):void

    {
        trace(ev.target.data.toString());  //THIS OUTPUTS CORRECTLY
        //OUTPUT for this trace is as follows
        //athleteName=ankur&email=email@yahoo.com&password=newpass&personalBest=9.58&shirtNumber=10         

        trace(ev.target.data.email.toString()); //LINE WITH ERROR
    }
```

Here is the relevant php code from the php file that I am loading

```
print "athleteName=".$_SESSION[athleteName];
print "&email=".$_SESSION[email];
print "&password=".$_SESSION[password];
print "&personalBest=".$_SESSION[personalBest];
print "&shirtNumber=".$_SESSION[shirtNumber];
print "&country=".$_SESSION[country];
```

I think error is maybe due to the way I am printing in php? But I am not sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, `URLLoader` loads data as text, so `email` doesn't exist on the raw `String`. Try setting:

```
phpLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
```